# How to overwrite the values of the first column in every rows in a HTML tbody table with JavaScript and with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, html-table

Here is a table example:

```
<table id="tableId">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>line number</th>
   <th>value</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>value 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>value 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="relineing" onclick="reLineNumbering('tableId')"/>
```

I want only the "line number"s to be in sequence like this:

```
<table id="tableId">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>line number</th>
   <th>value</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>value 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>value 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="relineing" onclick="reLineNumbering('tableId')"/>
```

I've tried both of the snippets below:

```
function reLineNumbering(tableId) {
  $('#'+tableId+' tbody').each(function (i) {
    this.rows[i].cells[0].text('i');
  });
}

function reLineNumbering(tableId) {
  var rowCount = $('#'+tableId+' tbody tr').length;
  for (var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    $('#'+tableId+' tbody').rows[i].cells[0].text(i);
  }
}
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: JavaScript and Java are the same thing in the same way as a Caterpillar resembles a Cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will change the first column to a sequential number starting from 1:

```
function reLineNumbering(tableId){
    $('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr').each(function(i, val){
        $('td:first', this).text(i+1); 
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JDLVC/1/)

Plain Javascript - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHNAT/1/):

```
function reLineNumbering(tableId){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var total = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<total; i++){
        if(i > 0){
            table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Or by creating the text node instead of setting `innerHTML`. In this simple scenario the use of `innerHTML` isn't a problem, but usually you will want to work with DOM elements and set the text node instead of setting the HTML:

```
function reLineNumbering(tableId){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var total = table.rows.length, text, cell;
    for(var i=0; i<total; i++){
        if(i > 0){
            text = document.createTextNode(i);
            cell = table.rows[i].cells[0];
            cell.removeChild(cell.firstChild);
            cell.appendChild(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the "this" word here? The current 'td' in the loop?

Comment: `this` is the current `<tr>` in the loop, so by passing `this` as the second argument, it's limiting the selector to that context, which makes sure it applies the `i+1` to the `<td>` in the current `<tr>`. If you didn't include `this`, it would set the text for all cells.

Comment: thank you! it works, but for some reason this doesn't work: `$('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr')` only this is working: `$('#' + tableId + '  tbody > tr')`. i don't know why, but it cannot find the tbody with the ">".

Comment: It's working in the fiddle so there must be something different about your HTML, most like the tbody is not in the same place as in the fiddle. The `>` is the child selector so it will only select the tbody that's a direct child of the table, by changing to a space, it becomes an descendant selector, so it will find the tbody anywhere under the table.

Comment: it doesn't matter, because the table has only 1 tbody :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#tableId > tbody > tr').find('td:first').text(function(idx, text){
    return idx + 1
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4kWeD/)

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct answer:

```
function reLineNumbering(tableId) {
        var myTable=document.getElementById(tableId);
        var rowCount = myTable.rows.length;
        for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            myTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a VanillaJS version of the same thing:

```
(function(t)
{
    for(var i=1;i<t.rows.length;i++)
    {
        t.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML += ' Vanilla';
    }
}(document.getElementById('tableId')));
```

[Which I added to the fiddle of Arun](http://jsfiddle.net/g3WZF/1/)

I post it here, because it's not an awful lot longer than the jQ version of the same code, but it *is* faster.
You can change it to:

```
var t = document.getElemebtById('tableId');
for(var i=1;i<t.rows.length;i++)
{
    t.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = 1 + i;//number tbl
}
```

If you don't feel comfortable using the IIFE.

PS: the loop could be simplified to:

```
for(var i=1;i<t.rows.length;)//do nothing here
{
    t.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i++;//increment i here
}
```